# Fire function when async DOM rendering is finished

Tags: angular, masonry

We have one issue with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) grid in Angular 2 application.

We need to call masonry init after DOM is ready and content loaded.
I tried with all Angular 2 lifecycle events but it doesn't work in all scenarios.

We are using ngrx - redux and here is piece of code how I tried to achive this:

In constructor I'm getting data from state

```
  constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>) {

        this.recommended$ = this.store
          .select('layout')
          .pluck('data');
      }
```

and in `ngAfterViewInit` I'm subscribed to above data and when it comes I want to initialize Masonry grid.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.recommended$           
      .subscribe((item: boolean) => {
        if (item) {
         new Masonry(this.masonryGrid.nativeElement, {});
        }
      });
  }
```

where `this.masonryGrid.nativeElement` is div ( grid ) in component template   `@ViewChild('masonryGrid') masonryGrid: ElementRef;`

If I try to open route where we are loading masonry grid directly it works.

But, if I'm coming to that route from another one this happens:
http://i.prntscr.com/23583025e000490c940caeb06c695890.png

and probably the main reason for that is because DOM is not rendered in `ngAfterViewInit()` ( in our case images are not )

http://i.prntscr.com/e46e87e5cf9740b6929ebe2e8635b040.png

Any advice is welcome and will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Angular can't provide an event that fires when a non-Angular component has completed rendering. Either the `Masonry` component renders sync, then just put the code inside the `if(item) {...}` or if it renders async, then `Masonry` needs to fire an event when it's done rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue. I don't have a clean solution and it seems like Angular doesn't have a way to detect this. In the meanwhile, a workaround is adding `delay(1000)` to the RxJS chain (or whatever value you consider appropriate for your case) so Angular can wait a bit before the DOM is rendered.

Another costly option would be adding `ngDoCheck` to verify if the element was rendered, but that will be executed every cycle.